# Show that group of homeomorphism of connected surface $M$ acts transitively

Tags: general-topology

My objective is to show that group of homeomorphism of connected surface $M$ acts transitively.

To start with, I have this : Let $0<x\leq y<1$ and $I=[0,1]$. Show that there is an homeomorphism $g$ on $I$ such as $g(x)=y$ and $g(0)=0$ and $g(1)=1$.

I found the function $f(x)= ty/x$ if $t$ is in $[0,x]$ and $(1-y)(t-x)/(1-x)+y$ if $t$ is in $[x,1]$.
$f$ is continuous and increasing.

Now, let K= [0,1]x[0,1], how i can construct an homeomorphism in K with h(x,1/2)=(y,1/2) and identity on boundaries ?
I tried h(t,v)=h(f(t),v) but it's not identity on boundaries.
Can you help me please ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: What part of the verification that your proposed function satisfies the conditions is giving you trouble?

Comment: I meant is it okay to start with this to prove the main point? If i have K= [0,1]x[0,1] , can i say that h is an homeomorphisme K->K and h(x, 1/2)=(y, 1/2) (and identity on boundaries of K) because h(t,v)=(f(t), v) ?

Comment: h is not identity on boundaries of K how i can change it please ?